# Why might a rectifier circuit not behave as expected?

Tags: power-supply, zener, bridge-rectifier

I'm building a power supply for a guitar amp in order to replace the poor quality PS/amp circuit that it had initially.  And after much deliberation and simulation this is what I designed:
[image]

Output is to be taken from the zeners, such that the amp will receive the 16V across ZD2, and the other parts of the amp receive the 32V across both.  The RC network C1R2 is supposed to smooth the output as well as prevent voltage doubling, and the PI filter after that should ensure that the final output is as clean DC as possible (this may be a little over-engineered, but I was given this to remove a noise issue in the first place).

The trouble is that instead of the expected output, the voltages across the capacitors is reading the RMS voltage for double the input AC voltage, and ZD2 is dropping nearly no voltage.

Why might these be so?

---

There are no obvious shorts around that particular zener, or at the receiving end of that 16V. The readings are as follows:

- IN: 48.6VAC
- D1: 22.4V D2: 22.5V D3: 21.8V D4: 21.9V
- R1: 62.0V R2: 7.5V R3: 33.7V
- C1: 62.0V C2: 54.5V C3: 54.2V
- L3: 0.29V
- ZD1: 20.5V ZD2: 8.0mV

Comment: What actual voltages are you seeing? About 65V is to be expected across the capacitors (C1 anyway). ZD2 dropping nearly no voltage? Maybe a short or the diode is installed backwards?

Comment: What zeners are they?

Comment: @Andyaka: the zeners are 1N4745A, specified to have the break down voltage of 16V and support 1W of current.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: As for their orientation, both are reverse biased.  There are no obvious shorts around that particular zener, or at the receiving end of that 16V. The readings are as follows: 
- IN: 48.6VAC
- D1: 22.4V D2: 22.5V D3: 21.8V D4: 21.9V
- R1: 62.0V R2: 7.5V R3: 33.7V
- C1: 62.0V C2: 54.5V C3: 54.2V
- L3: 0.29V
- ZD1: 20.5V ZD2: 8.0mV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overloading your zener diodes.

If a 16-volt zener is rated to handle 1 watt, that means you cannot put any more than

$$\frac{1 W}{16 V} = 62.5 mA$$

through it — preferably less.

Even when working correctly, your circuit is designed to put

$$\frac{54 V - 32 V}{220 \Omega} = 100 mA$$

through the two diodes.

It would appear that ZD2 has failed shorted, and ZD1 is now handling

$$\frac{54 V - 20 V}{220 \Omega} = 155 mA (3 W)$$

and probably getting quite warm in the process.

A better design would run the zeners at a much lower current, and use transistors to handle the power dissipation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUCF6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>